# Feign Client Call(to a http service) is converted from GET request to POST when the call is made in runtime

Tags: java, post, get, feign

I was trying to call a http GET service through feign client but I see the request being converted into POST before the call is made.

Without header the Get call works fine(I meant gives a 401 instead 404), the header content is expected by http service I'm trying to call, so cannot remove the header.

```
@FeignClient(name="commonservice")
@Path("/company/service/module")
public interface getCaseInfo{
 @GET
 @Path("/endpointURI/{pathparam}")
 public ResponseObject getCaseDetails(@PathParam("pathparam") String param, @RequestHeader Map<String,String> header) throws exception
}
```

/*TRIED @HeaderParam Annotation as well*/

The feign client call has to be made as GET request with Headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using @headerparam for each of the custom header parameter I had. **But it would still keep doing that GET to POST, if i use:
"@Headerparam/@HeaderMap Map headers"**

Updated code:
public ResponseObject getCaseDetails(@PathParam("pathparam") String param, @HeaderParam("custom_header1") String custom_header1,@HeaderParam("custom_header2") String custom_header2)

If someone can give me the reason on why a *map* wouldn't work, that would be great!